# how to implement a const field which in subClasses must be overwrite .net 4

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0

how to implement a `const field` which in subClasses must be overwrite, i'm using `.net 4, C#`

because i have many classes they `all have a const field`(with different value) called 'pName'.

so i want use a interface or abstract class or somthing as a parent and force these classes to override it.

it's **`CONST`** field

Comment: Not clear what do you want to override.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot `override` a `const`; nor can you declare it as `static` and `override` it there. What you *can* do is re-declare it, but that ***is not robust*** - in that which version gets used depends on which you ask for (entirely at compile-time - completely unrelated to polymorphism):

```
public new const int Foo = 12;
```

I would suggest you use a `virtual` or `abstract` property:

```
public virtual int Foo { get { return 4; } } // subclasses *can* override
public abstract int Foo { get; } // subclasses *must* override
```

and `override`:

```
public override int Foo { get { return 12; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You request is contradictional: you can not define a constant value which is possible to override, so change in derived class.

What you *can* do is define *default* value in base class, and override it in derived one.

```
public class Base 
{
    public static reaondly int DEFAULT_BASE_VALUE = 0,
    private int _someValue = DEFAULT_BASE_VALUE;   //ASSIGN DEFAULT VALUE

    public virtual int SomeValue {
        get {
           return _someValue;
        }
    } 
}

public class Derived : Base
{

     public override int SomeValue {
        get {
           return -3;    //CHANGE VALUE OF BASE CLASS 
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, constants aren't virtual members.

What you could do instead is have a *readonly* property e.g

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
    }

    protected int MyProperty { get { return 10; } }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
    }

    protected override int MyProperty { get { return 20; } }
}
```

Comment: Readonly is readonly: a subclass can't change the value - you would have to pass that down as `public DerivedClass() : base(20) {}` or similar

Comment: @MarcGravell Oops my bad I did mean to update this example as a virtual property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you can do is declare a abstract readonly property like so

```
abstract class A
{
        public abstract int ReadOnlyProp {get;}
}

class B : A
{
    public override int ReadOnlyProp
    {
        get { return 42; }
    }
}
```